# Jquery keyup/blur date and days calculation

Tags: jquery, forms, datepicker

I have a form which i would like to calculate the end date from the start date and the number of days selected.

So process......
Select days
Select start date
Auto populate enddate = starts days + days

I have got the following working but does anybody know how to populate with the calculation and so it has days and startdate inputed before the calculation takes place.

```
var $title3 = $("#enddate");
$("#startdate").keyup(function () {
    $title3.val(this.value);
});
$("#startdate").blur(function () {
    $title3.val(this.value);
});​
$("#days").keyup(function () {
    $title3.val(this.value);
});
$("#days").blur(function () {
    $title3.val(this.value);
});​


              echo'<table width="100%"><tr>
                <td class="label"><label for="days">Days:</label></td>
                <td class="field">
                <select id="days" name="days">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td class="status"></td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="label"><label for="startdate">Start Date:</label></td>
                  <td class="field"><input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" class="required" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                  <td class="status"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="label"><label for="enddate2">End Date:</label></td>
                  <td class="field"><input type="text" name="enddate2" id="enddate2" class="required" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                  <td class="status"></td>
                </tr></table>';
```

**MOD**

This is a solution i have come up with but need the maxDate for the enddate to be selectedDate + 5days excluding weekends. How would i write this?

Also how could i work out the difference in days from the 2 outcomes of enddate and startdate but exclude the weekends?

```
var $ac_start_date = '<?php echo $ac_end_date ?>',
    $ac_start_date_flip = '<?php echo $ac_end_date_flip ?>',
    $ac_start_parsed = Date.parse($ac_start_date),
    _today = new Date().getTime();

// For Opera and older winXP IE n such
if (isNaN($ac_start_parsed)) { 
    $ac_start_parsed  = Date.parse($ac_start_date_flip);
}

var _aDayinMS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; 

// Calculate the difference in milliseconds
var difference_ms = Math.abs($ac_start_parsed - _today);

// Convert back to days and return
var DAY_DIFFERENCE = Math.round(difference_ms/_aDayinMS);   



// do initialization here
$("#startdate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '0:+100',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate + 5days excluding weekends);
            },              
            minDate: '+1d',         
            maxDate: '+' + (DAY_DIFFERENCE + 1) + 'd'
});

// do initialization here
$("#enddate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '0:+100'
});
```

AHHA...

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
```

Comment: your startdate textbox is set to readonly, are you using JS calendar?

Comment: Edited my question twice...... My solution worked but still need to work out the difference in days between startdate and enddate excluding weekends